# electron-packager Cannot read property 'info' of undefined

Tags: electron, electron-packager

I was trying to create package of legacy electron app using electron-packager but got an error like below. I have search several questions in stackoverflow with no luck.

```
electron-packager . MyApp --platform=win32 --arch=x64 --no-prune --overwrite --ignore=/node_modules

Packaging app for platform win32 x64 using electron v3.1.13
Cannot read property 'info' of undefined
```

Below are the installed package in the project:

```
+-- electron-builder@20.44.4
+-- electron-json-storage@4.1.6
+-- electron-packager@15.5.2
+-- electron-winstaller@3.0.4
+-- electron@3.1.13
+-- history@4.9.0
+-- macaddress@0.2.9
+-- moment@2.29.4
+-- node-sass@4.14.1
+-- rc-tooltip@3.7.3
+-- react-bootstrap@1.6.6
+-- react-dom@16.8.4
+-- react-redux@6.0.1
+-- react-router-dom@4.3.1
+-- react-router@4.3.1
+-- react-scripts@2.1.5
+-- react@16.8.3
`-- redux@4.0.1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I change tools and follow according to electron documentation about [application packaging](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/application-distribution). I change to electron-forge and follow the steps. It works better than packager.

Answer (score 4):

`electron-packager@15.5.2` caused the same issue for me. A slight downgrade to `electron-packager@15.5.1` made it working again!

Comment: Thank you it can pack the app successfully and create an exe for me. But when I ran the exe it only show blank white screen, despite running perfectly well using "electron ."

Comment: Glad it helped. Your follow-up issue unfortunately might be related to something else but the package version, as i do not have problems here.

Answer (score 1):

Same here, `electron-packager@15.5.2` caused the same issue for me.

From my side, I upgraded to `electron-packager@16.0.0` to made it working again.
I did not find a related issue on GitHub.

Comment: v16 makes it fail for me, might be interesting to exchange electron versions? Mine was v12

Comment: I'm using `electron@16.2.8`